# paper_trail gives me errors with existing User model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paper-trail-gem

Is there any conflict to set a `User` model to be versioned with `paper_trail`? I have a model 'User' as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail

end
```

The problem is that whenever I call `user#versions` I get an exception:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'versions.user_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `versions`.* FROM `versions` WHERE (`versions`.user_id = 6)
```

(exception thrown when called `versions` on a `User` with `id = 6`.

I also have problem when I am trying to save a `User`. I get the following exception:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Column 'item_id' cannot be null: INSERT INTO `versions` (`event`, `created_at`, `item_id`, `item_type`, `object`, `whodunnit`) VALUES ('update', '2011-11-17 10:38:43', NULL, NULL, '--- ....
```

which seems that `save` does not populate the `item_id` and `item_type`.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had also added `has_many :versions` in my `User` model and there was a conflict.

To avoid the conflict, I followed what the `paper_trail` mentions in the documentation:

`has_paper_trail :versions => :paper_trail_versions`